# Saving a file.txt with a name from TextInput

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

I'm quite new to python and kivy and I'm trying to create simple drawing App on my tablet. I would like to save the output as a .txt file with the name from TextInput (username). 
(also sorry for my english)

How can I also to make the timer start first after clicking on the Submit button?

```py
from kivy.app import App
# kivy.require("1.8.0")
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.graphics import Line
from kivy.core.image import Image
from kivy.uix.button import Button

import os
import time

from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('graphics', 'width', '700')
Config.set('graphics', 'height', '700')
Config.write()

from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, FadeTransition
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty

# changing color to white
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.graphics import Color
Window.clearcolor = (1, 1, 1, 1)
# mode rgba

# Exact date
# now = time.localtime(time.time())
# str(now[3]) + ":" + str(now[4]) + ":" + str(now[5])

class MainScreen(Screen):   

    username = ObjectProperty(None)

    def btn(self):
        x = str(self.username.text)
        print(x)
        return x

class SecondScreen(Screen):
    pass
class AnotherScreen(Screen):
    pass
class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    pass   

class DrawInput(Widget):

    filename = MainScreen().btn

    time_start = time.time()

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):

        # print(touch.spos, touch.pos)
        timing_ms = time.time() - self.time_start

        if os.path.isfile(self.filename+".txt") is True:
            x = open(self.filename+".txt", "a")
            x.write(str(timing_ms) + "\t"
                    + str(touch.spos[0]) + "\t" + str(touch.spos[1]) + "\t" +
                     str(touch.pos[0]) + "\t" + str(touch.pos[1]) + "\t" + "touch" + "\n")
        else: 
            x = open(self.filename+".txt", "w")
            x.write(str(timing_ms) + "\t"
                    + str(touch.spos[0]) + "\t" + str(touch.spos[1]) + "\t" +
                     str(touch.pos[0]) + "\t" + str(touch.pos[1]) + "\t" + "touch" + "\n")              
        with self.canvas:
            Color(0, 0, 0)
            touch.ud["line"] = Line(points = (touch.x, touch.y))



    def on_touch_move(self, touch):

        # print(touch.spos, touch.pos)       
        timing_ms = time.time() - self.time_start

        if os.path.isfile(self.filename+".txt") is True:
            x = open(self.filename+".txt", "a")
            x.write(str(timing_ms) + "\t"
                    + str(touch.spos[0]) + "\t" + str(touch.spos[1]) + "\t" +
                     str(touch.pos[0]) + "\t" + str(touch.pos[1]) + "\t" + "move" + "\n")
        else:
            x = open(self.filename+".txt", "w")         
            x.write(str(timing_ms) + "\t"
                    + str(touch.spos[0]) + "\t" + str(touch.spos[1]) + "\t" +
                     str(touch.pos[0]) + "\t" + str(touch.pos[1]) + "\t" + "move" + "\n")

        touch.ud["line"].points += (touch.x, touch.y)

    def on_touch_up(self, touch):     

        # print("Released!", touch)
        timing_ms = time.time() - self.time_start

        if os.path.isfile(self.filename+".txt") is True:
            x = open(self.filename+".txt", "a")
            x.write(str(timing_ms) + "\t"
                    + str(touch.spos[0]) + "\t" + str(touch.spos[1]) + "\t" +
                     str(touch.pos[0]) + "\t" + str(touch.pos[1]) + "\t" + "released" + "\n")
        else:
            x = open(self.filename+".txt", "w")
            x.write(str(timing_ms) + "\t"
                    + str(touch.spos[0]) + "\t" + str(touch.spos[1]) + "\t" +
                     str(touch.pos[0]) + "\t" + str(touch.pos[1]) + "\t" + "released" + "\n")


presentation = Builder.load_file("applepen.kv")

class ApplePen(App):

    def build(self):
        return presentation

if __name__=="__main__":
    ApplePen().run()
```

```
# File name: ApplePen.py
#: import FadeTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.FadeTransition

ScreenManagement:
    transition: FadeTransition()
    MainScreen:
    SecondScreen:
    AnotherScreen:

<MainScreen>:
    name: "main"
    # define global variable username
    username: username

    GridLayout:
        cols:1
        # organise the window
        size: root.width, root.height

        GridLayout:
            cols: 2
            Label: 
                text: "Username: "
                color: 0.5,0.5, 0.5, 1
            TextInput:
                id: username
                multiline: False

        Button:
            color: 0,1,0,1
            font_size: 50
            #size_hint: 0.5, 0.5
            text: "Submit"
            on_press: root.btn()
            on_release: app.root.current = "drawing"


<SecondScreen>:
    name: "drawing"

    FloatLayout:
        DrawInput
        Button:
            color: 0,1,0,1
            font_size: 25
            size_hint: 0.3, 0.3
            text: "finished"
            on_release: app.root.current = "other"


<AnotherScreen>:
    name: "other"
    Button:
        on_press: app.stop()
        text: "Finished"
        font_size: 50
```

The error: 
if os.path.isfile(self.filename+".txt") is True:
 TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'method' and 'str'.
I tried str() but then the name of the file is something like this: bound method MainScreen.btn of

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: @el3ien, I would like to save my txt and naming it after input from TextInput. In this case it would be the username.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Error

> ```
>  if os.path.isfile(self.filename + ".txt") is True:
> ```
>
> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'method' and 'str'

## Root Cause

The code, `filename = MainScreen().btn` instantiated another new instance of `MainScreen` and pointing to the method `btn()`. This new instance is different from that instance instantiated, `MainScreen:` in the kv file. Therefore, the value assigned to `self.filename` is `method MainScreen.btn` which is of type `class method`.

## Solution

There are two solutions to the problem.

### Method 1

#### Py file

- Add `import` statement for `StringProperty`
- In `class DrawInput()`, replace `filename = MainScreen().btn` with `filename = StringProperty('')`

Snippets - py

```
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, StringProperty
...
class DrawInput(Widget):
    filename = StringProperty('')
```

#### kv file

- Add `id: main` to instantiated widget, `MainScreen:`
- Add `id: drawing` to instatiated widget, `DrawInput:`
- Add `on_pre_enter` event to initialize `filename`

Snippets - kv

```
ScreenManagement:
    transition: FadeTransition()
    MainScreen:
        id: main
    SecondScreen:
    AnotherScreen:
...
<SecondScreen>:
    name: "drawing"
    on_pre_enter:
        self.ids.drawing.filename = self.manager.ids.main.username.text

    FloatLayout:
        DrawInput:
            id: drawing
```

### Method 2

Using the combination of the following:

- Use `App.get_running_app()` to get the `app` object
- Use `root.get_screen('main')` to get `MainScreen` object
- Use `username.text` to extract the TextInput's text

#### Snippet

```
def on_touch_down(self, touch):
    self.filename = App.get_running_app().root.get_screen('main').username.text
```

## Note - Loading kv file

In your Kivy app, try not to load *kv* file using both methods i.e. loading by name convention and loading by Builder. Use only one method.

## [Kivy Language » How to load KV](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/lang.html#how-to-load-kv)

There are two ways to load Kv code into your application:

**By name convention:**

Kivy looks for a Kv file with the same name as your App class in lowercase, minus “App” if it ends with ‘App’ e.g:

```
ApplePenApp -> applepen.kv
```

or

```
ApplePen -> applepen.kv
```

If this file defines a *Root Widget* it will be attached to the App’s *root* attribute and used as the base of the application widget tree.

**By Builder convention:**

You can tell Kivy to directly load a string or a file. If this string or file defines a root widget, it will be returned by the method:

```
Builder.load_file('path/to/file.kv')
```

or:

```
Builder.load_string(kv_string)
```

## Snippet - Py

```
class ApplePen(App):
    pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    ApplePen().run()
```

Comment: thank you very much for the explanation, it solved my problem!

Answer (score 1):

You can save a file named from a textinput in kivy by doing something like this:
Try this example:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder


KV = """

BoxLayout:
    TextInput:
        id: ti
    Button:
        text: "Save"
        on_release:
            f = open(ti.text, "w")
            f.close()

"""


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)


MyApp().run()
```

Comment: It does work but how can now write my data to this new file? I mean, i still have to define filename in my drawing methods.

Comment: @dawidarchibald what kind of data. Just text?

Comment: Just text: the x and y touch coordinates and timestamps.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in `filename = MainScreen().btn` as this is a method. I suppose you need to use `filename = MainScreen().btn()`

Comment: I've been there and that is the error: ```Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/Users/davidarchibald/Documents/Scripts/ApplePen.py", line 50, in <module>
     class DrawInput(Widget):
   File "/Users/davidarchibald/Documents/Scripts/ApplePen.py", line 52, in DrawInput
     filename = MainScreen().btn()
   File "/Users/davidarchibald/Documents/Scripts/ApplePen.py", line 39, in btn
     x = str(self.username.text)
 AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text' ```

Comment: That is because `self.username` is None. You need to set it to some value first.

Comment: I did it in the kv file?:                                                                                               ```Button:
           color: 0,1,0,1
           font_size: 50
            #size_hint: 0.5, 0.5
            text: "Submit"
            on_press: root.btn() 
            on_release: app.root.current = "drawing"```                                             Which value do you mean?

Comment: Then you need to leave `filename = MainScreen().btn` and call it every time you use it like `self.filename()`.

Comment: The same Error: ```AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'```

Comment: I could recommend using `StringProperty` for `username` instead of general `ObjectProperty` then as it should have a valid default value.